# Ventana PopUp sin salirse de ella

Tags: javascript, vb.net

Tengo una ventana `PopUp` en mi página pero deseo que nadie pueda salirse al darle `Click`a la página anterior como si fuera un `ShowDialog`. Uso `VB.Net`

Comment: Has de hacer la ventana `Modal`. Mira en sus propiedades

Comment: Muéstranos como inicias tu ventana modal, así como esta la pregunta hay demasiadas repuestas posibles para que sea útil.

Answer (score 3):

Desde `html`:

```
<a data-controls-modal="your_div_id" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" href="#">
```

Desde `jQuery`:

```
$('#idDelModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})
```

Otros atributos `data`:

```
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  backdrop   |  Incluye un elemento modal-backdrop. Como alternativa, |
|             |  especifique `static` para un fondo que no cierre el   |
|             |  modal en clic.                                        |
|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------|
|  keyboard   |  Con valor `booleano: true` evita cerra el modal cuando|
|             |  se presiona la tecla `escape`                         |
|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------|
|    show     |  Muestra el modal cuando se inicializa                 |
|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------|
|   remote    |   deprecado desde v3.3.0. Carga desde una vía remota   |
|             |  el contenido del modal                                |
|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------|
```

Answer (score 1):

Te recoumendo el plugin **BlockUI** de `jquery`

http://malsup.com/jquery/block/

Te anexo ejemplo de como se usa, saludos.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() { 
 
        $('#prueba').click(function() { 
            $.blockUI({ message: $('#modal'), css: { width: '275px' } }); 
        }); 
 
        $('#yes').click(function() { 
            // update the block message 
            $.blockUI({ message: "<h1>Procesando...</h1>" }); 
 
            $.ajax({ 
                url: 'wait.php', 
                cache: false, 
                complete: function() { 
                    // unblock when remote call returns 
                    $.unblockUI(); 
                } 
            }); 
        }); 
 
        $('#no').click(function() { 
            $.unblockUI(); 
            return false; 
        }); 
 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
<input id="prueba" type="submit" value="Mostrar Modal" /> 
 
 
<div id="modal" style="display:none; cursor: default"> 
        <h1>Presiona el botón para cerrar.</h1> 
        <input type="button" id="yes" value="Procesar" /> 
        <input type="button" id="no" value="Salir" /> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con este código el cual no permite volver atrás, para poder implementarlo copia este código en el  de la pagina que necesites

`<script type="text/javascript">
        history.forward();
</script>`

Comment: Has de explicar al usuario qué hace tu código. No lo dejes ahí sin más. Puede que sea simple pero si no lo entiende no podrá modificarlo o darle más uso en otras partes de su programa